# Multithreading in Windows Forms

Tags: multithreading, winforms, assembly, time, c++-cli

I wrote app, Caesar Cipher in Windows Forms CLI with dynamic linking libraries(in C++ and in ASM) with my alghorithms for model(eciphering and deciphering). That part of my app is working.

Here is also a multithreading from Windows Forms. User can chose number of threads(1-64). If he chose 2, message to encipher(decipher) will be divided on two substrings which will be divided on two threads. And I want to execute these threads paraller, and finally reduce cost of execution time.

When user push encipher or decipher button there will be displayed enciphered or deciphered text and time costs for execution functions in C++ and ASM. Actualy everything is alright, but times for greater threads than 1 aren't smaller, they are bigger.

There is some code:

```
/*Function which concats string for substrings to threads*/
        array<String^>^ ThreadEncipherFuncCpp(int nThreads, string str2){
            //Tablica wątków
            array<String^>^ arrayOfThreads = gcnew array <String^>(nThreads);
            //Przechowuje n-tą część wiadomosci do przetworzenia 
            string loopSubstring;
            //Długość podstringa w wiadomości
            int numberOfSubstring = str2.length() / nThreads;
            int isModulo = str2.length() % nThreads;
            array<Thread^>^ xThread = gcnew array < Thread^ >(nThreads);

            for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0 && numberOfSubstring != 0)
                    loopSubstring = str2.substr(0, numberOfSubstring);
                else if ((i == nThreads - 1) && numberOfSubstring != 0){
                    if (isModulo != 0)
                        loopSubstring = str2.substr(numberOfSubstring*i, numberOfSubstring + isModulo);
                    else
                        loopSubstring = str2.substr(numberOfSubstring*i, numberOfSubstring);
                }
                else if (numberOfSubstring == 0){
                    loopSubstring = str2.substr(0, isModulo);
                    i = nThreads - 1;
                }
                else
                    loopSubstring = str2.substr(numberOfSubstring*i, numberOfSubstring);

                ThreadExample::inputString = gcnew String(loopSubstring.c_str());
                xThread[i] = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&ThreadExample::ThreadEncipher));
                xThread[i]->Start();
                xThread[i]->Join();
                arrayOfThreads[i] = ThreadExample::outputString;
            }
            return arrayOfThreads;
        }}
```

Here is a fragment which is responsible for the calculation of the time for C++:

```
    /*****************C++***************/
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    array<String^>^ arrayOfThreads = ThreadEncipherFuncCpp(nThreads, str2);
    auto elapsed = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

    long long milliseconds = chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();
    double micro = milliseconds;
    this->label4->Text = Convert::ToString(micro + " microseconds");
    String^ str3;
    String^ str4;
    str4 = str3->Concat(arrayOfThreads);
    this->textBox2->Text = str4;
    /**********************************/
```

And example of working:
For input data: "Some example text. Some example text2."
Program will display: "Vrph hadpsoh whaw. Vrph hadpsoh whaw2."

Times of execution for 1 thread:

```
C++ time: 31231us. 
Asm time: 31212us.
```

Times of execution for 2 threads:

```
C++ time: 62488us. 
Asm time: 62505us.
```

Times of execution for 4 threads:

```
C++ time: 140254us. 
Asm time: 124587us.
```

Times of execution for 32 threads:

```
C++ time: 1002548us. 
Asm time: 1000020us.
```

How to solve this problem?

- I need this structure of program, this is academic project.
- My CPU has 4 cores.

Comment: You are calling Join right after Start?  So you start a thread, then wait for it to complete before starting the next thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not going any faster is because you aren't letting your threads run in parallel.

```
xThread[i] = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&ThreadExample::ThreadEncipher));
xThread[i]->Start();
xThread[i]->Join();
```

These three lines create the thread, start it running, *and then wait for it to finish*. You're not getting any parallelism here, you're just adding the overhead of spawning & waiting for threads.

If you want to have a speedup from multithreading, the way to do it is to start all the threads at once, let them all run, and then collect up the results.

In this case, I'd make it so that `ThreadEncipher` (which you haven't shown us the source of, so I'm making assumptions) takes a parameter, which is used as an array index. Instead of having `ThreadEncipher` read from `inputString` and write to `outputString`, have it read from & write to one index of an array. That way, each thread can read & write at the same time. After you've spawned all these threads, then you can wait for all of them to finish, and you can either process the output array, or since `array<String^>^` is already your return type, just return it as-is.

Other thoughts:

- You've got a mix of unmanaged and managed objects here. It will be better if you pick one and stick with it. Since you're in C++/CLI, I'd recommend that you stick with the managed objects. I'd stop using `std::string`, and use `System::String^` exclusively.
- Since your CPU has 4 cores, you're not going to get any speedup by using more than 4 threads. Don't be surprised when 32 threads takes longer than 4, because you're doing 8x the string manipulation, and you've got 32 threads fighting over 4 processor cores.
- Your string splitting code is more complex than it needs to be. You've got five different cases in there, I'd have to sit down and think about it for a while to be sure it's correct. Try this:

  ```
  int totalLen = str2->length;
  for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
      int startIndex = totalLen * i / nThreads;
      int endIndex = totalLen * (i+1) / nThreads;
      int substrLen = endIndex - startIndex;

      String^ substr = str2->SubString(startIndex, substrLen);
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Very helpfull, I just finished the project.

Comment: I realize that often after execute app, values of times are bad. Independently of the data, values of timers are often 0 or rarely about 15600-15900.

Comment: What you're seeing there is the resolution of your timer. Several timers in Windows have a resolution of 1/64th second, or 15625 microseconds. The stopwatch class in .Net should have better resolution, but you should really be executing your test a few thousand times and taking the average.

Comment: But why, one time it gives me correct times, and one time uncorrect(0 oraz 15xxx) ?